# django: set permission on built-in 'revision' model?

Tags: django

I use the built in "revision" app, import it in settings.py.
How can I manually assign a "add_revision" permission to someone?
I'm familiar with permissions in general, but this one is odd, somewhere around here:

```
app_label = 'revision.revisions.revision.Revision' #~~~~????
model = 'Revision' #~~~~?????

ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_label, model=model)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app name is `reversion`.

Read the documentation:
https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/wiki

Comment: ..and if the peermissions are still missing from auth_permissons table, run syncdb, that will add them